# EditText height for fit a certain numbers of character

Tags: android, android-edittext

There's a way to set height of an EditText for contains at least n character ?

Comment: That's why wrap content invented... You can't accurately set the height of edittext according to characters.

Comment: if i use wrap_content and initially edittext is empty, i obtain an edittext height only "one row"

Comment: Are you having problems in the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some number of ways that you can limit the editText as number of characters within multiple line as well.

Firstly, set this in your .xml:

```
android:inputType="textMultiline"
android:maxLength="n"
```

Secondly, you can also use a way around to reach your goal. Here it is. Implement TextWatcher to let user enter just 'n' characters. Whenever user enters 'n' characters, set the EditText to non-editable. And also set OnFocusChangeListener to it.

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry);  
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(20)});
```

For more details and also explanation of textWatcher, you can have a look [number of input characters](http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1815641/).

For more manipulation on multiple lines. You can set the number of lines this way, after you have set textMultiline, you can use any or some of below:

```
android:lines="8"
android:minLines="6"
android:maxLines="10"
android:scrollbars="vertical/horizontal"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your `EditText`.

If you want a single row of text only, use `android:singleLine="true"`

If you want it to have a minimum height set, use `android:minHeight="x dp"`

If you want it to be exactly `n` lines tall, use  `android:lines`

Comment: i don't want edittext as single line, but multiple line.

Comment: `android:inputType="textMultiline"` ?

Comment: but if you set as multiline, when layout is created (with wrap_content), edittext is high only one row, then scale automatically when text reach end of line

Comment: minHeight require a dimension (in pixels, in dp, or in mm) that i couldn't know in advice (i don't know how many pixels are a single character )

Comment: Ok, but i need to calculate in advice how many lines occupy n characters into an EditText! it's not the best way, because each time i change font size, fort type, n, screen width, i need to calculate again it